# How would I design interdependent foreign keys in SQL / SQLALCHEMY

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Lets assume I have a database with the tables User, Country and Language. Also, a country can have several languages, but each language is only spoken in one country.

```
User
> id
> name
> country (foreign key Country.id)
> language (foreign key Language.id)

Country
> id
> name

Language
> id
> name
> country (foreign key Country.id)
```

Assume a user enters his information in a form and chooses a country. He can now only select from the languages that are spoken in that country.

I work with sqlalchemy. I am also be interested in SQL / Mysql.

How would I model that constraint? Does it even make sense to model that constraint? 
What is the proper terminology for such a situation? Interdependent foreign keys?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just drop the `country` foreign key from `user`, in which case you'd access the country of a user through their language. I think it should be logically sound, given your other constraints. If a language is only spoken in a country, and a user speaks said language, their country is that country.

Comment: The question is good but the example is unrealistic. How about replacing languages with locations?  The ER model isn't expressive enough to model this and I would guess SQL isn't either. Object-oriented models naturally support this. I found this question searching with "interdependent foreign keys"...

Comment: @IljaEverilä, you are absolutely right. I guess I oversimplified.

Comment: @MiroLehtonen, I am not sure what you mean by replacing languages with locations. Anyway, I guess I was undercaffeinated when I asked the question. I posted the way I solved it below. I hope it helps for your case.

Comment: Just saying that the majority of the world's population speaks more than one language, whereas everyone has only one "current location". User - language, language - country, and even user - country are many-to-many relationships in real life. This is a theoretical example, right?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to simplify, but I guess I oversimplified.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, the example in my question was oversimplified and could have easily been solved by dropping `country` from the `User` table.

What I ended up doing was an additional table that take into account the 'dependencies' between country and language.

```
  User
  > id (PK)
  > name
  > linguistic_combo.id

  Linguistic_Combos
  > country.id (PK)
  > language.id (PK)

  Country
  > id (PK)
  > name

  Language
  > id (PK)
  > name
```

Now every user has a language country combination which will be valid, and all valid combinations are in the table `Linguistic_Combos`.

`country.id` and `language.id` in `Linguistic_Combos` form a composite primary key.

In comparison to my original question, a language can be spoken in different countries.

Comment: I get that "linguistic_Combos" is a "join table" but it doesn't look like any combination of country and language has to be unique. I would remove that "id" column from the Linguistic_Combos table and make country+language the primary key. Then the combinations would be unique.

Comment: Compared with the original question, the problem changed so that a one-to-many relationship became a many-to-many relationship. A new table is the obvious solution. If it's a one-to-many relationship like in the original question, a new table is a less obvious solution, in my opinion. But it is a way to guarantee that the user's language is spoken in the user's country.

Comment: @MiroLehtonen, you are absolutely right about the primary key and removing the id. It's been a long time since I worked on this.